# How to enable Remove Animation from Settings -> Accessibility android

Tags: android, android-layout, animation, android-source, preference

I need to enable Remove Animation from Accessibility. By default, it has been disabled.

Below is the picture.

[image]

How to enable Remove Animation by default?

Here is the code where it has been disabled by default.

```
     private SwitchPreference mToggleDisableAnimationsPreference;

       // Settings that should be changed when toggling animations
    private static final String[] TOGGLE_ANIMATION_TARGETS = {
            Settings.Global.WINDOW_ANIMATION_SCALE, Settings.Global.TRANSITION_ANIMATION_SCALE,
            Settings.Global.ANIMATOR_DURATION_SCALE
    };
    private static final String ANIMATION_ON_VALUE = "1";
    private static final String ANIMATION_OFF_VALUE = "0";

    mToggleDisableAnimationsPreference =
                (SwitchPreference) findPreference(TOGGLE_DISABLE_ANIMATIONS);

     updateDisableAnimationsToggle();

  @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceTreeClick(Preference preference) {

     if (mToggleDisableAnimationsPreference == preference) {
            handleToggleDisableAnimations();
            return true;
        } 
     return super.onPreferenceTreeClick(preference);

} 

  private void handleToggleDisableAnimations() {
        String newAnimationValue = mToggleDisableAnimationsPreference.isChecked()
                ? ANIMATION_OFF_VALUE : ANIMATION_ON_VALUE;
        for (String animationPreference : TOGGLE_ANIMATION_TARGETS) {
            Settings.Global.putString(getContentResolver(), animationPreference, newAnimationValue);
        }
    }

 private void updateDisableAnimationsToggle() {
        boolean allAnimationsDisabled = true;
        for (String animationSetting : TOGGLE_ANIMATION_TARGETS) {
            if (!TextUtils.equals(
                    Settings.Global.getString(getContentResolver(), animationSetting),
                    ANIMATION_OFF_VALUE)) {
                allAnimationsDisabled = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        mToggleDisableAnimationsPreference.setChecked(allAnimationsDisabled);
    }
```

This is the code from aosp. Now where exactly I need to enable by disabling animation by default?

Answer (score 1):

you can try to execute `handleToggleDisableAnimations` (a bit modified), but I doubt that common app can change this setting, afaik there is no permission for that

```
private void handleDisableAnimations(boolean enabled) {
    String newAnimationValue = enabled
            ? ANIMATION_ON_VALUE : ANIMATION_OFF_VALUE;
    for (String animationPreference : TOGGLE_ANIMATION_TARGETS) {
        Settings.Global.putString(getContentResolver(), animationPreference, newAnimationValue);
    }
}
```

Comment: okay. Let me try this. So by default, checkbox should be made true and pass this value in this?

Comment: you have [`getString`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Global#getString(android.content.ContentResolver,%20java.lang.String)) method for obtaining current state (if this is possible), this should be default value (same as in settings)